# JsonP scriptTag extjs4.1 issue

Tags: cross-domain, jsonp, extjs4.1

**i got the following server response:**

> callback({
>       "data": [
>           {
>               "id": "13_gnomodotiseis",
>               "id1": 13,
>               "title": "5/2009 ΓΝΜΔ ΕΙΣΑΠ  2009",
>               "text": "5/2009 ΓΝΜΔ ΕΙΣΑΠ ",
>               "model": "gnomodotiseis",
>               "body": "σίλει...",
>               "type": "text",
>               "history": "old",
>               "url": "",
>               "search_tag": "Γνωμοδοτήσεις",
>               "new_element": "true"
>           }
>       ],
>       "dataset": 1 })

**I have a store definition like this:**

```
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8090/'; 

Ext.define('Ktimatologio.store.NewSingleBlockStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'widget.newsingleblockstore',

    requires: ['Ktimatologio.model.NewSingleBlockModel'],

    model: 'Ktimatologio.model.NewSingleBlockModel',

    groupField: 'search_tag',

    fields: [    
        {name:'id', mapping:'id'},
        {name:'id1', mapping:'id1'},
        {name: 'text', mapping: 'text'},
        {name: 'title', mapping: 'title'},
        {name: 'fek', mapping: 'fek'},
        {name: 'date', mapping: 'date'},
        {name: 'descr', mapping: 'description'},
        {name: 'model', mapping: 'model'},
        {name: 'body', mapping: 'body'},
        {name: 'type', mapping: 'type'},
        {name: 'history', mapping: 'history'},
        {name: 'src', mapping: 'url'},
        {name: 'search_tag', mapping: 'search_tag'},
        {name: 'new_element', mapping: 'new_element'},
        {name: 'new_table', mapping: 'new_table'}
        ],

    autoLoad: true,    

    proxy: {
        //type:'ajax',
        type:'jsonp',
        url: baseUrl + 'openbd/ktimatologio-final/resources/cfScripts/nea_stoixeia/GetNews.cfc?',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        extraParams: {
            method: 'jsonP'
            },
        reader:{
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    } 

});
```

**The url that i am seeing in firebug:**

> http://localhost:8090/openbd/ktimatologio-final/resources/cfScripts/nea_stoixeia/GetNews.cfc?&_dc=1345305032559&method=jsonP&page=1&start=0&limit=25&group=[{"property"%3A"search_tag"%2C"direction"%3A"ASC"}]&sort=[{"property"%3A"search_tag"%2C"direction"%3A"ASC"}]&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback2

Firebug gives me error: **"ReferenceError: callback is not defined"**

My questions are:

From where does Ext.data.JsonP.callback2 pops up in the url?

What am i missing here? How jsonP in Extjs4.1 works?

I really need help on this one.

Thank you in advance,

Tom

Greece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong function name in the response.  If you look at the request url, you can see that it is sending in the function name that your response needs to call, and you need to use it in the response data: &callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback2, so the response should call the function Ext.data.JsonP.callback2 instead of just plain callback.  So in the case of your example, the server should be returning this instead as the response:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback2({ "data": [ { "id": "13_gnomodotiseis", "id1": 13, "title": "5/2009 ΓΝΜΔ ΕΙΣΑΠ 2009", "text": "5/2009 ΓΝΜΔ ΕΙΣΑΠ ", "model": "gnomodotiseis", "body": "σίλει...", "type": "text", "history": "old", "url": "", "search_tag": "Γνωμοδοτήσεις", "new_element": "true" } ], "dataset": 1 })
```

This is because callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback2 was sent in the request.

Comment: Many, many thanks! I haven't figured out that i had to place "Ext.data.JsonP.callback2" to server's request. How fool am i! Thank you again!