# How to send Cross Domain Request to Load the Grid Ext JS 4.1

Tags: extjs, grid, jsonp, extjs4.1

How to load the data into a grid sending a cross domain request to a ws using AJAX? I am able to send the request but how I can load the data into the grid using a callback method?

Inside the contoller file:

```
if(searchText){
    var resultGrid = Ext.getCmp('myResultGrid');
    store.setProxy({
                            type: 'ajax',
                            // cross domain request
                            url:"http://3.xxx.xxx.77/cs/sid/"+searchText,
                            actionMethods:{read:'GET'},
                            pageParam: false, //to remove param "page"
                            startParam: false, //to remove param "start"
                            limitParam: false,
                            timeout:9000000,
                            noCache : true,
                            reader: {
                            type: 'json'
                            }
                    });


    resultGrid.store.load({
      scope: this,
      callback: function(records, operation, success) 
      {
          var totalcount= 0;
          totalcount = records.count(true);

          if(totalcount > 0)
          {
              // Load the data into grid ???

          }
          else
          {
              Ext.Msg.alert("No Records found.");   
          }
      }
    });
}
```

Store file: **SearchResultsStore.js**

```
     Ext.define('AM.store.SearchResultsStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.SearchModel',
    autoLoad: false
});
```

Model:

```
   Ext.define('AM.model.SearchModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['slno', 'customer']
});
```

json response

```
        [{"slno": "12454","customer": "acd"}]
```

Please help am stuck!!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Aren't you complicating things? If the grid has its `store:` config set to your store, once the store loads, the grid will automatically reflect the changes.

Comment: agreed, just look at some simple grid examples from the official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ajax to send requests accross domains, which is the actual problem here.  You are assuming you have to do something in the load callback because you are not receiving data back in the first place, this has nothing to do with your problem and you do not need to use the callback.  What you need to do is configure your store with a 'jsonp' proxy instead of ajax which will let you do cross domain calls:

```
store.setProxy({
                                type: 'jsonp',
                                // cross domain request
                                url:"http://3.xxx.xxx.77/cs/sid/"+searchText,
                                actionMethods:{read:'GET'},
                                pageParam: false, //to remove param "page"
                                startParam: false, //to remove param "start"
                                limitParam: false,
                                timeout:9000000,
                                noCache : true,
                                reader: {
                                type: 'json'
                                }
                        });
```

Comment: So no need to define a callback method... this will be handled by JSONP right. Is there anything needs to be done on the server side i.e. in json response. I tried this one but not able to load the JSON data into the grid.

Comment: I'm not really an expert with jsonp, so my example may not be completely accurate, you probably do need to define a callback method.  See this guy's question for a real-life example that I helped him work through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021947/jsonp-scripttag-extjs4-1-issue/12042732#12042732

Comment: After changing to jsonp the request is going as GET request[earlier internally its converted to OPTIONS ] with a callback function name. And its calling the callback method.  No changes made in the json response. I am using the same json but its loading.... loading... loading... So how I can capture the data and set this to the store.  Request sent: 10.xxx.xxx.14/ab/resources/scripts/ab/data/bomsearchresults.json?_dc=1345576045890&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1 and here is the callback method:

Comment: resultGrid.store.load({
scope: this,
callback: function(records, operation, success) 
{// Here I need to set the data
alert(operation+ " "+success);}});

Comment: does the json returned look something like this:

Comment: Ext.data.JsonP.callback1([{"slno": "12454","customer": "acd"}]);

Comment: Reimius thanks for your help. It worked. So wat I did I used JSONP and no callback method as JSNOP takes care of that. So ensured the json response should append Ext.data.JsonP.callback2([{"slno": "12454","customer": "acd"}]); and the content-type must set as text/javascript.